# What 3D Model Viewer for Flutter allows for changing controls - in my case to make them correct for a 3D map?

Tags: flutter, 3d, flutter-dependencies, model-viewer, 3d-mapping

I am searching for a way to display a 3D map, created in blender, as a 3D model in Flutter *with 3D map controls*.  This means one finger to pan, two to rotate instead of the reverse found in a typical model viewer.  I have tried several at this point and none have done the trick.  I really don't want to have to fully code my own additions to a model viewer unless they are relatively simple.

I tried using model-viewer-plus at first, and it's quick loading and allows for camera movement restriction, both things I need.  However there is no option for editing controls besides enabling/disabling them.  Other model viewers have a similar problem and may even load too slow on top of that.